# cronjob to start node.js using pm2 (similar to forever)

Tags: node.js, cron, pm2

I'm fairly new to cron. I'm not sure how cron path variable. When i start my process using ssh session, I'd write command:  `NODE_ENV=test pm2 start /home/myuser/webapps/myapp/app.js`. How should this be written in crontab? Something like this? `@reboot  NODE_ENV=test env PATH=$PATH:/home/myuser/bin pm2 start /home/myuser/webapps/myapp/app.js`

I'd appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need this crontab ? To launch it on startup ?

You can try the command `pm2 startup centos|ubuntu`

Comment: yeah, but I can't use this, because on the server I use, I don't have root/sudo privileges.